# Why ElasticBeanstalk CPU alarm checks maximum not average?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set an alarm average cpu utilization (1 minutes) > 65 on my Node.js elasticbeanstalk. While installing Node.js dependencies, the EC2 instance is using a lot of CPU resources.

However, I found that the "average" CPU usage didn't exceed this threshold, while the "maximum" CPU utilization exceeded this threshold. Why the elasticbeanstalk alarm occurs even if the average cpu utilization doesn't exceed the threshold?

[[image: Maximum CPU Utilization]

[image: Average CPU Utilization]

Why is it happening? I'm tired of false positive CPU alarms :(
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I set an alarm average cpu utilization (1 minutes) > 65 on my Node.js
> elasticbeanstalk.

It means that the cloud watch alarm trigger will take an average of 1 minute and trigger the alarm if it crosses 60.

In the first screenshot, it seems that the CPU utilization was high from almost 9:57 until 10:07 for 10 minutes.

In the second screenshot, it shows the average was a max of 30 during this period. Let's do some math to understand it:

Cpu utilization was not consistently high, the graph shows the peak recorded and if the CPU is utilised 90% for 3 seconds and 10% for 57 seconds, the average will be 27% high for 1 minute.

The above case is almost similar to it. That's why you see different graphs in maximum and average.